# Why I cannot change the value of my variable?

Tags: reactjs, date

I have 3 components :

The first one is this one :

```
const App = () =>{
const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date())
return (
<MyComponent date={date} setDate={(mydate) => {setDate(mydate)}} />
)
}
export default App;
```

The second is that one :

```
const MyComponent = (props) =>{
    return (
    <MyComponent2 date={props.date} setDate={(mydate) => {props.setDate(mydate)}} />
    )
    }
    export default MyComponent;
```

And the last one is this one :

```
const MyComponent2 = (props) =>{
    props.setDate(new Date("February 5, 2001 18:15:00"))
    console.log(props.date)


    return (
    <p>Hello</p>
    )
    }
    export default MyComponent2;
```

But I got the following error : `TypeError: props.setdate is not a function`

Could you help me please ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not receive the props, change your declaration for this :

```
const MyComponent = (props) => ....
const myComponent2 = (props) => ...
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot the props but I put them in my code and unfortunately it does not work :/

Comment: I try your code and its working, except for the facts its doing a infinite loop since you are calling setDate and its causing to re-render all the time. Your error that you quote in your question is : props.setdate, the good syntax would be : props.setDate. are you sure in your actual code you are not missing the capital D of date ?